# how to reset to factory

Tags: format

while updating some sort of virus protection programms on the computer it goes off. as a result, the computer is not working at the moment, I can not enter the terminal, and the screen lights up gray and black and goes out . i tried pressing f11 while the computer was turning on and it didn't help, I don't know what to do, I'd appreciate if you could help.

and i understand from computer littelbit and english is my 2 language so i wish when you tell me what to do please use a basic and clear language

computer information :
think pad lenovo x240
system :
ubuntu linux
thank you

Comment: I don't know which "anti virus" stuff you installed, but make sure it is from the repository (or via SotwareManager) and **not** from some obscure website

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** I agree with @kanehekili: noting "some sort of virus protection progamms [sic]" is vague and not helpful. Also, to help in better troubleshooting your issue, please edit your question to include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're running. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no "factory reset".

Reinstall the OS.

Here's the [official tutorial to Install Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop) if you need a reference.

Comment: thank you for your help